# Visual Studio 2013 settings for CPLEX 12.6

Tags: c++, cplex, visual-studio-2013

I tried to configure my VS2013 to work with CPLEX 12.6 on a 32bit, I succeed to add it.

[I read this (VS2012) but I can't find a clear solution with VS2013](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=7dd43f9a-3e87-43a3-8575-8def07b0894a)

VS2013 shows me a lot of errors like :

Error    2    error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in Source.obj    C:\Users\juste 3al faza\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\cplex\ilocplex.lib(ilocplex.obj)    cplex

and

Error    1    error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1800' in Source.obj    C:\Users\juste 3al faza\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\cplex\ilocplex.lib(ilocplex.obj)    cplex

and

Error    168    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void __thiscall std::basic_ostream >::_Add_vtordisp2(void)" (__imp_?_Add_vtordisp2@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAEXXZ) referenced in function "[thunk]:public: virtual void __thiscall std::basic_ostream >::_Add_vtordisp2`vtordisp{4294967292,8}' (void)" (?_Add_vtordisp2@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@$4PPPPPPPM@7AEXXZ)    C:\Users\juste 3al faza\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\cplex\concert.lib(iloenv.obj)    cplex

and

Error    143    error LNK2005: _vsprintf_s already defined in LIBCMT.lib(vsnprnc.obj)    C:\Users\juste 3al faza\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\cplex\MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR120.dll)    cplex

---

I don't know if Cplex 12.6 compatible with VS2013, but I download Cplex 12.6 and I install it without any errors on win8

So, Any help plz!!!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't yet a version of CPLEX for VS2013. See the previously asked question [Need more explanation on LNK2038 mismatch dectected for '_MSC_VER'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143152/need-more-explanation-on-lnk2038-mismatch-dectected-for-msc-ver), and in particular, the response from Xavier Nodet that points to the system requirements info on the IBM website.